# Does strength of victory include teams a team has tied?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, tie-breaker

In figuring the NFL's strength of victory tie-breaker, what about teams a team has tied? In other calculations, a tie is counted as half a victory.

Answer (score 1):

## No. "Victory" means winning, not tying.

The strength of victory counts only the actual victories, where the team won.

The NFL tiebreaker procedures do not list any alternative definition or calculation for this, so it can be assumed to have the simplest form possible: the combined record of teams beaten, expressed as a winning percentage.

This calculation will count the beaten teams' ties as a half-win, as usual.

Comment: Ties count towards victories for winning percentage, but not for strength of victory. May be the way the rule is intended to be impemented, doesn't mean it makes sense.

Comment: By the time one reaches that level of tiebreaker, including half-winning-records is more effort than is worthwhile. Sure, it's easy enough to calculate, especially with computers that could run it almost perfectly real-time, but it's one more step that might confuse fans.